# matlab: gscatter hold on doesn't work

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to have "plot" and "gscatter" in the same subplot and I used hold on...but it didn't work, here is my code:

```
figure('Name','Different Group of Users','NumberTitle','on', 'Position',  [130 150 570 510]);
subplot(2,2,1)
x_1 = 0 : 300;
y_1 = theta * x_1;
gscatter(X1, Y1, B, '','xos');
xlabel('time');
ylabel('number of members-seed1');
hold on;
plot(x_1, y_1);
hold off;
```

Comment: It works for me; can you provide code with representative data so we can reproduce the problem? thanks!

Comment: You're plotting your points at the same locations as your `gscatter` points. Are you sure they aren't both there and you just can't see them because they're on top of one another

Comment: I guessed the problem is something about hold on or gscatter but the problem was about "theta" and it was sovled. tnx!